# Bash: "printf %q $str" deletes spaces when in scripts. (Alternatives?)

Tags: bash, printf

**printf %q** should quote a string.  However, when executed into a script, it deletes the spaces.

This command:

```
printf %q "hello world"
```

outputs:

```
hello\ world
```

which is correct.

This script:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="hello world"
printf %q $str
```

outputs:

```
helloworld
```

which is wrong.

If such behavior is indeed expected, what alternative exists in a script for quoting a string containing any character in a way that it can be translated back to the original by a called program?

Thanks.

Software: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

EDITED: Solved, thanks.

Comment: Removed the 'SOLVED' prefix in the title of your post. In StackOverflow.com, you don't mark a problem as solved by prefixing the heading with 'SOLVED' You accept an answer or you post your own answer and accept it by clicking the tick-mark below the voting buttons near the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use:

```
printf %q "$str"
```

Example:

```
susam@nifty:~$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

str="hello world"
printf %q "$str"
susam@nifty:~$ ./a.sh 
hello\ world
```

When you run `printf %q $str`, the shell expands it to:

```
printf %q hello world
```

So, the strings `hello` and `world` are supplied as two separate arguments to the `printf` command and it prints the two arguments side by side.

But when you run `printf %q "$str"`, the shell expands it to:

```
printf %q "hello world"
```

In this case, the string `hello world` is supplied as a single argument to the `printf` command. This is what you want.

Here is something you can experiment with to play with these concepts:

```
susam@nifty:~$ showargs() { echo "COUNT: $#"; printf "ARG: %s\n" "$@"; }
susam@nifty:~$ showargs hello world
COUNT: 2
ARG: hello
ARG: world
susam@nifty:~$ showargs "hello world"
COUNT: 1
ARG: hello world
susam@nifty:~$ showargs "hello world" "bye world"
COUNT: 2
ARG: hello world
ARG: bye world
susam@nifty:~$ str="hello world"
susam@nifty:~$ showargs $str
COUNT: 2
ARG: hello
ARG: world
susam@nifty:~$ showargs "$str"
COUNT: 1
ARG: hello world
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to q being a valid format parameter in the man page.  Could someone explain why %q works?  Is it deprecated and now there's a new preferred format parameter?  I don't see anything in the man page that describes this functionality.

Comment: From the output of `help printf` - `%q quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input`.

Comment: @AnthonyDiSanti, this is from Bash, so you can find it in `man bash` or `help printf` in a Bash shell. Maybe you were looking at `man 1 printf` or `man 3 printf`? `%q` doesn't apply to those.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Satisfies these requirements

1. Accept arbitrary input that may include shell special characters
2. Does not output escape character, the "\"

```
#! /bin/bash

FOO='myTest3$;  t%^&;frog now! and *()"'

FOO=`printf "%q" "$FOO"`                        # Has \ chars
echo $FOO

# Eat all the \ chars
FOO=$(printf "%q" "$FOO" | sed "s/\\\\//g")     # Strip \ chars

echo $FOO
```

Comment: So, if I echo $FOO prior to the escape command, the output is exactly the same as your final echo. So it appears that you're unescaping your escaped string, in which case what's the point of escaping it? (at least in the context shown here)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
printf %q "${str}"
```

in your script.