# Bash Script Variable with special character in a CURL POST

Tags: bash, variables, curl, post

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

WEBHOOK="https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces....." <-- CUT FOR SECURITY REASON

ALARMA="${VMWARE_ALARM_NAME}"
TARGET="${VMWARE_ALARM_TARGET_NAME}"
VALOR="${VMWARE_ALARMVALUE}"
DESCRIPCION="${VMWARE_ALARM_EVENTDESCRIPTION}"
ESTADO="${VMWARE_ALARM_NEWSTATUS}"

DATA='{
  "cardsV2": [
    {
      "cardId": "unique-card-id",
      "card": {
        "header": {
          "title": "VCSA-MGMT",
          "subtitle": "<alarma>",
          "imageUrl": "https://developers.google.com/chat/images/quickstart-app-avatar.png",
          "imageAltText": "Avatar"
        },
        "sections": [
          {
            "widgets": [
              {
                "textParagraph": {
                  "text": "<b>TARGET:</b> <target>",
                }
              },
              {
                "textParagraph": {
                  "text": "<b>VALOR:</b> <valor>"............... <--- CUT the code to make simple and short question

DATA="${DATA/<alarma>/$ALARMA}"
DATA="${DATA/<target>/$TARGET}"
DATA="${DATA/<valor>/$VALOR}"
DATA="${DATA/<descripcion>/$DESCRIPCION}"
DATA="${DATA/<estado>/$ESTADO}"

echo $DATA >/var/macro/log.txt

curl -i \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-X POST --data "$DATA" ${WEBHOOK} >>/var/macro/log.txt`
```

My question is:
when some one of the variable (example "TARGET") have special character like ( or ' or "
I get error 400 since the POST of the CURL does not like it.
How do I send the entire variable without worrying about having it?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the LOG when i have the error (I MARK IT IN BOLD):

```
{ "cardsV2": [ { "cardId": "unique-card-id", "card": { "header": { "title": "VCSA-MGMT", "subtitle": "Prueba-webhook", "imageUrl": "https://developers.google.com/chat/images/quickstart-app-avatar.png", "imageAltText": "Avatar" }, "sections": [ { "widgets": [ { "textParagraph": { "text": "<b>TARGET:</b> test_dhcp", } }, { "textParagraph": { "text": "<b>VALOR:</b> ", } }, { "textParagraph": { "text": "***<b>DESCRIPCION:</b> Reconfigured test_dhcp on esxi012 in dc-mgmt. Modified: config.hardware.device(3002).deviceInfo.summary: "Remote ATAPI" -> "ISO (vsan-mgmt) e18bd164-1e86-0996-e091-84160c743e80/ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso"; config.hardware.device(3002).backing: (deviceName = "", useAutoDetect = false) -> (fileName = "ds:///vmfs/volumes/vsan:5260d6deb1050bf6-e96811bf431767b6/e18bd164-1e86-0996-e091-84160c743e80/ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso", datastore = 'vim.Datastore:5fb71ad9-1d79-4d23-a644-a13fd149ab44:datastore-13', backingObjectId = <unset>); Added: Deleted: " } }, { "textParagraph": { "text": "<b>***ESTADO:</b> Warning" } } ] } ] } } ], }
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request^M
Vary: X-Origin^M
Vary: Referer^M
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8^M
Date: Fri, 08 Mar 2024 16:25:45 GMT^M
Server: ESF^M
Cache-Control: private^M
X-XSS-Protection: 0^M
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN^M
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff^M
Set-Cookie: COMPASS=dynamite-integration=CgAQmZStrwYaUQAJa4lXTN6PPtCvYGfhNmpdcYqpwF8TE22nUazE0CPHQPr4qGfhkqHSAq-B6JV7LPEXw3lU3-2Ffh3uNE7qP81tTLb-KupZoW_-8NfJEfGB2TAB; expires=Mon, 18-Mar-2024 16:25:45 GMT; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly^M
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000^M
Accept-Ranges: none^M
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding^M
Transfer-Encoding: chunked^M
^M
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "*message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\neviceInfo.summary: \"Remote ATAPI\" -\u003e \"IS\n *                   ^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
```

To resolve my problem:
I try save the variable and format with PRINTF or other comands like SED to replace character but it only a workaround.

Comment: json is hard to manipulate in bash.  Have you any language interpreters that can handle json more elegantly, like python or ruby?  Here' for example, is a python one-liner that reads its stdin and produces a formatted, escaped json string containing the same: `echo -n  'hi " world' | python3 -c "import json, sys, os; print(json.dumps(sys.stdin.read()))"` produces `"hi \" world"`

Comment: if you want to work with JSON in bash, use the `jq` utility rather than constructing strings yourself.

Comment: Thanks erik258 and Barmar... i forgot to say i worked in a PHOTOM OS... is the VMWARE SO. JQ command is available but i dont know how it helpme in my problem.

Comment: @OscarGutierrez `jq` can handle encoding special characters into valid JSON escape sequences. See ["Build a JSON string with Bash variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470049/build-a-json-string-with-bash-variables) and ["Trying to include a dynamic variable within JSON data of a Bash / Shell POST request to API endpoint"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495304/trying-to-include-a-dynamic-variable-within-json-data-of-a-bash-shell-post-req). Also, there are a couple of places you should double-quote variables; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point them out.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson you are great! I do some modification to my code and try. Later I'll tell you how it went. Regards.

Comment: I have progress. Now I got the quotes past but now parentheses appeared.
**JSON=$(printf "$DATA" "${DESCRIPCION//\"/\\\"}")**
Someone tellme how escapa varius characters in one 'printf'?? Regards

Comment: `printf %q "$DATA"` may help, This Q/A discusses some of the issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045001/bash-printf-q-str-deletes-spaces-when-in-scripts-alternatives . Search for others with `[bash] printf %q` . Good luck.

Comment: @OscarGutierrez I'm not sure what that `printf` command is supposed to do, but it's almost certainly wrong -- the first argument to `printf` should be a format string that says how to print the data in the rest of the arguments, so it should never contain data itself. Also, I'm not sure why you're adding more escapes to `$DESCRIPCION`; that shouldn't be necessary.